# About "The comparative, the comparative" expression

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis, syntax

In my school days, I was taught the English sentence structure, "The comparative + Subject + Verb, the comparative + Subject + Verb."

In a certain software help document, I saw a sentence, "The lower the difference, the better the x will be..."

According to the sentence structure which I learnt at school (decades ago), the sentence would be "The lower the difference "**is**" (Verb), the better the x will be..."

Is it grammatically correct to omit this "**is**" (Verb)?

Comment: It's OK. The verb "be" can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
It helps me a lot and I highly appreciate it.